# How to write in a file N times in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write in a file N times in Prolog. I came up with this solution:

```
response(M,Out,N) :-
   write('How do you feel ?'),
   open('output.txt',write,Out),
   read(M),
   write(Out,M),
   close(Out),
   response(M,Out,S),
   S is N - 1.
response(M,Out,0).
```

The basic idea is to read an emotion from keyboard and write it into a file called `output.txt`. It gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Uninstantiated argument expected, found <stream>(0x60000311fb00) (stream-argument)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [12] open('/Users/dylan/Desktop/output.txt',write,<stream>(0x60000311fb00))
ERROR:   [11] response(sad,<stream>(0x60000311fb00),_10234) at /Users/dylan/Desktop/suggestsong.pl:14
ERROR:   [10] response(sad,<stream>(0x60000311fb00),3) at /Users/dylan/Desktop/suggestsong.pl:18
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /Applications/SWI-   Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1158
Exception: (11) response(sad, <stream>(0x60000311fb00), _9654) ? creep
Exception: (10) response(_9306, _9308, 3) ? creep
```

Thw predicate without the loop works fine, but it's just one time reading and is not good for the purpose.

Can please someone help me ? Thank you all.

Comment: Use e.g. `trace` to see what's happening - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the solution!

I actually found also another simple way to solve this, using recursion:

```
% chat with user 
chat :-
  ask("y").


ask("y") :-
   write('How do you feel?: '),
   read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, E),
   %assert(emotion(E)), %assert a fact or rule into database
   suggest(emotion(E)),
   write("Continue: (y or n) "),
   read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Respond),
   ask(Respond).


% The user type "n", hence computing and writing results into file
ask("n") :- 
  tell('output.txt'), 
  %listing(emotion/1), 
  listing(genre/2),  %lookup result of genre/2 into database
  told.
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform the file writing:

```
append_file_output(File, Output) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        open(File, append, Stream),
        writeln(Stream, Output),
        close(Stream)
    ).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- append_file_output('test.txt', woo).
true.

?- append_file_output('test.txt', hoo2).
true.
```

```
$ cat test.txt
woo
hoo2
```